# How does a date search parameter work with a Period field?

Tags: hl7-fhir, dstu2-fhir

I'm looking at the [DSTU2 CarePlan](http://hl7.org/fhir/careplan.html) resource which has a [date search parameter](http://hl7.org/fhir/search.html#date) that searches the CarePlan.period field.

The DSTU2 search page specifies that when the target value is a Period, the target is explicitly a range (though the upper or lower bound may not be actually specified on the resource), with the following example:

```
date=ge2013-03-14    |    Includes a period "from 21-Jan 2013 onwards"
```

Does the target explicitly being a range mean that the date search parameter in this case should be treated as a range from "ge2013-03-14" to "highest possible date"?

In this case, would all CarePlans that have a period that encompasses some subset of that range qualify?  For example, would a CarePlan with period:

```
"period": {
  "end": "2013-03-15"
}
```

also be included in the results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All dates that aren't fully expressed down to the 10th of a millisecond are automatically treated as periods for comparison purposes.  And matches would be based on whether there's a non-empty intersection between the period specified in the search and the period specified in the instance.  So yes, in the example you provided, ge2013-03-14 would search for any timestamp from 2013-03-14T00:00:00.0000 and higher in the receiver's default timezone.  From a matching perspective, the instance you indicated would be treated as having a start of negative-infinity and an end that would encompass all times from 2013-03-15T00:00:00.0000 through 2013-03-15:23:59:59.9999.  That would have an overlap of the range of just under 2 days.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer: Yes
The longer answer:

```
"period": {
  "end": "2013-03-15"
}
```

means the target range is **(-∞, 2013-03-15T00:00:00Z)**

The search query is

```
date=ge2013-03-14
```

means the search range is **[2013-03-14T00:00:00Z, +∞)**
The search prefix is **ge** and there exists overlaps between search range and target range. so the target is included in the search result.

If the prefix is **eq** then target range must be fully included in the search range.